# Из обозревателя решений не удаляется папка

Tags: visual-studio

Не могу из обозревателя решений удалить папку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как удалить?

Answer (score -2):

[How to hide bin and obj folder from being displayed in solution explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26141001/4827341)

Попробуй скрыть её если не получается удалить

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Скрывать вместо удаления - костыль. От этого потом только лишние проблемы будут.